# How can I use d3 force to space out overlapping points on a map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a map that has some overlapping points. I'm using a quadtree and turf.js to determine, when I click on a point, how many other points are within a 30 mile radius.

What I'd like to do (if there's more than one point in that radius) is use d3.forceSimulation to equally spread out the overlapping points.

This is a pretty close example of what I want to do, but uses d3v3 and google maps: http://bl.ocks.org/cdmahoney/raw/9876525/?raw=true

I have included d3.forceSimulation and when I click on a place with more than one point within the 30 mile radius, the points do take on the force-- but they move up to the left hand corner of the page.

How can I get the points to push out in even distances from where I click on the map, like this: [image]

Help very much appreciated!!

```js
        let margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10, left: 0 },
            width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        let projection = geoAlbersUsaTerritories.geoAlbersUsaTerritories()
            .scale(width)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2.2]);

        const path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-160))
            .stop()

        let eventX,
            eventY

        const formatDate2 = d3.timeFormat("%m-%Y")

        const svg = d3.select("#content")
            .append("svg")
            .attr('id', 'map')
            .style("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

        const map = svg.append('g')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .attr('class', 'map')

        const landmass = map.append('g').attr('class', 'land')

        const places = map.append('g').attr('id', 'places')

        svg.append('ellipse').classed("radius", true).attr('id', 'locate')

        d3.json("https://unpkg.com/us-atlas@3.0.0/states-10m.json").then(function (usa) {

            landmass.selectAll('path')
                .data(topojson.feature(usa, usa.objects.nation).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("class", "outline")
                .attr('fill', '#ccc')
                .attr("stroke", "#999")

            landmass.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(usa, usa.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("class", "mesh")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                .attr('stroke', 'white')
        });

        const data = [
            {
                "id": 3448,
                "name": "General Edward Lawrence Logan Intl",
                "city": "Boston",
                "faa": "BOS",
                "latitude": 42.364347,
                "longitude": -71.005181
            },
            {
                "id": 3453,
                "name": "Metropolitan Oakland Intl",
                "city": "Oakland",
                "faa": "OAK",
                "latitude": 37.721278,
                "longitude": -122.220722
            },
            {
                "id": 3454,
                "name": "Eppley Afld",
                "city": "Omaha",
                "faa": "OMA",
                "latitude": 41.303167,
                "longitude": -95.894069
            },
            {
                "id": 3457,
                "name": "Wichita Mid Continent",
                "city": "Wichita",
                "faa": "ICT",
                "latitude": 37.649944,
                "longitude": -97.433056
            },
            {
                "id": 3458,
                "name": "Kansas City Intl",
                "city": "Kansas City",
                "faa": "MCI",
                "latitude": 39.297606,
                "longitude": -94.713905
            },
            {
                "id": 3459,
                "name": "Dane Co Rgnl Truax Fld",
                "city": "Madison",
                "faa": "MSN",
                "latitude": 43.139858,
                "longitude": -89.337514
            },
            {
                "id": 3462,
                "name": "Phoenix Sky Harbor Intl",
                "city": "Phoenix",
                "faa": "PHX",
                "latitude": 33.434278,
                "longitude": -112.011583
            },
            {
                "id": 3467,
                "name": "Spokane Intl",
                "city": "Spokane",
                "faa": "GEG",
                "latitude": 47.619861,
                "longitude": -117.533833
            },
            {
                "id": 3469,
                "name": "San Francisco Intl",
                "city": "San Francisco",
                "faa": "SFO",
                "latitude": 37.618972,
                "longitude": -122.374889
            },
            {
                "id": 3472,
                "name": "Gainesville Rgnl",
                "city": "Gainesville",
                "faa": "GNV",
                "latitude": 29.690056,
                "longitude": -82.271778
            },
            {
                "id": 3473,
                "name": "Memphis Intl",
                "city": "Memphis",
                "faa": "MEM",
                "latitude": 35.042417,
                "longitude": -89.976667
            },
            {
                "id": 3484,
                "name": "Los Angeles Intl",
                "city": "Los Angeles",
                "faa": "LAX",
                "latitude": 33.942536,
                "longitude": -118.408075
            },
            {
                "id": 3486,
                "name": "Cleveland Hopkins Intl",
                "city": "Cleveland",
                "faa": "CLE",
                "latitude": 41.411689,
                "longitude": -81.849794
            },            
            {
                "id": 3494,
                "name": "Newark Liberty Intl",
                "city": "Newark",
                "faa": "EWR",
                "latitude": 40.6925,
                "longitude": -74.168667
            },
            {
                "id": 3502,
                "name": "Dallas Love Fld",
                "city": "Dallas",
                "faa": "DAL",
                "latitude": 32.847111,
                "longitude": -96.851778
            },
            {
                "id": 3550,
                "name": "George Bush Intercontinental",
                "city": "Houston",
                "faa": "IAH",
                "latitude": 29.984433,
                "longitude": -95.341442
            },
            {
                "id": 3559,
                "name": "El Paso Intl",
                "city": "El Paso",
                "faa": "ELP",
                "latitude": 31.80725,
                "longitude": -106.377583
            },
            {
                "id": 3566,
                "name": "William P Hobby",
                "city": "Houston",
                "faa": "HOU",
                "latitude": 29.645419,
                "longitude": -95.278889
            },
            {
                "id": 3570,
                "name": "Pittsburgh Intl",
                "city": "Pittsburgh",
                "faa": "PIT",
                "latitude": 40.491467,
                "longitude": -80.232872
            },
            {
                "id": 3576,
                "name": "Miami Intl",
                "city": "Miami",
                "faa": "MIA",
                "latitude": 25.79325,
                "longitude": -80.290556
            },
            {
                "id": 3582,
                "name": "Long Beach",
                "city": "Long Beach",
                "faa": "LGB",
                "latitude": 33.817722,
                "longitude": -118.151611
            },
            {
                "id": 3585,
                "name": "Indianapolis Intl",
                "city": "Indianapolis",
                "faa": "IND",
                "latitude": 39.717331,
                "longitude": -86.294383
            },
            {
                "id": 3589,
                "name": "Westchester Co",
                "city": "White Plains",
                "faa": "HPN",
                "latitude": 41.066959,
                "longitude": -73.707575
            },
            {
                "id": 3697,
                "name": "La Guardia",
                "city": "New York",
                "faa": "LGA",
                "latitude": 40.777245,
                "longitude": -73.872608
            },
            {
                "id": 3747,
                "name": "Chicago Midway Intl",
                "city": "Chicago",
                "faa": "MDW",
                "latitude": 41.785972,
                "longitude": -87.752417
            },
            {
                "id": 3797,
                "name": "John F Kennedy Intl",
                "city": "New York",
                "faa": "JFK",
                "latitude": 40.639751,
                "longitude": -73.778925
            },
            {
                "id": 3830,
                "name": "Chicago Ohare Intl",
                "city": "Chicago",
                "faa": "ORD",
                "latitude": 41.978603,
                "longitude": -87.904842
            }
        ]

        d3.selectAll('.close').on('click', function () {
            d3.selectAll('.popup').remove()
        })
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.latitude = +d.latitude;
            d.longitude = +d.longitude;
        })
        d3.selectAll('.location').remove()

        let locations = places.selectAll(".location")
            .data(data);

        locations.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr('id', d => 'n' + d.id)
            .attr("class", 'location')
            .attr('cx', d => projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0])
            .attr('cy', d => projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1])
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr('fill', 'green')
            .style('stroke', '#fff')
            .style('stroke-width', .5)
            .style("opacity", .75)
            .on('click', function (event, d) {
                simulation.stop()

                var isSelectedCode = d.detention_facility_code
                var isSelectedName = d.name
                var whichclass = d3.select(this).attr("class").split(' ');
                let activeIndex = whichclass.indexOf('active')

                var sel = d3.select(this);
                sel.raise();

                let latlng = [d.longitude, d.latitude]
                $('#clickedFacility').text(d.name)
                $('#slider').removeClass('hide')
                showRadius(latlng, far)

            })
            .on("mouseover", function (event, d) {
                var sel = d3.select(this);
                sel.raise();

                let tooltip_str = d.name
                tooltip.html(tooltip_str)
                    .style("visibility", "visible");
            })
            .on("mousemove", function (event, d) {
                tooltip.style("top", event.pageY - (tooltip.node().clientHeight + 5) + "px")
                    .style("left", event.pageX - (tooltip.node().clientWidth / 2.0) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (event, d) {
                var sel = d3.select(this);
                sel.lower();
                tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
            })

        locations
            .transition()
            .duration(100)
            .attr("class", d => "location " + d.name.replace(/[\s]/g, '') + ' ' + d.type_detailed.replace(/\s+|[,\/]/g, "") + ' closed' + d.is_closed)
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr('fill', 'green')

        locations.exit()
            .remove();

        const tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip");

        var info = svg.append("div")
            .attr("class", "info");

        const quadtree = d3.quadtree()
            .x(d => +d.longitude)
            .y(d => +d.latitude)
            .addAll(data);

        let miles = 30

        let far = (1 / 60) * miles; // in degrees

        function showRadius(evt, far) {

            d3.select('ellipse.radius').remove();

            let radiusCircle = map.append("ellipse").classed("radius", true).attr('id', 'locate')

            let xy = projection.invert(evt)
            console.log('xy', xy)

            let xyObject = { "longitude": evt[0], "latitude": evt[1] }
            radiusLng = evt[0] + far
            radiusLat = evt[1] + far
            radiusLngLat = [+radiusLng, +radiusLat]
            radiusPoint = projection(radiusLngLat)
            console.log('radiusPoint', radiusPoint)

            radiusX = Math.abs(evt[1] + far)
            radiusY = Math.abs(evt[0] + far)

            radiusToPoint = projection([radiusY, radiusX][0])

            d3.select('ellipse.radius').classed('hide', false)
            d3.select('ellipse.radius').classed('show', true)

            let radiusprojx = projection(evt)[0]
            let radiusprojxN = projection(evt)[0] - eventX
            let radiusprojy = projection(evt)[1]
            let radiusprojyN = projection(evt)[1] - eventY

            radiusCircle
                .attr('cx', d => (projection(evt)[0]))
                .attr('cy', d => (projection(evt)[1]))
                .attr('rx', 20)
                .attr('ry', 20)

            let hits = [];
            quadtree.visit(nearest(xyObject, far, hits))

            for (i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                let line = turf.lineString([[evt[1], evt[0]], [hits[i].latitude, hits[i].longitude]]);
                let length = turf.length(line, { units: 'miles' });
                hits[i].distance = +length.toFixed(2) + ' miles';
            }
            hits.sort(function (a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.distance, b.distance) })

            let locationsInRadius = hits.map(a => a.id);
            console.log('locationsInRadius', locationsInRadius)

            d3.selectAll('.location').attr('fill', 'green')
            locationsInRadius.forEach(function (d, i) {
                d3.select('#n' + d).attr('fill', 'blue')
            })

            let total_count = hits.length

            $("#hitnumber").text(total_count + " airports within 30 miles")

            d3.selectAll('.list-item').remove()

            let listItem = d3.selectAll('#hits').selectAll('text')
                .data(hits)
                .attr('padding-left', '20px')
                .enter().append('div').attr('class', 'list-item')
                .html(d => d.name + "<br/>Lat: " + d.latitude + "<br/>Lng: " + d.longitude + "<br/>Distance: " + d.distance)

            if (hits.length == 1) {
            } else {
                const hitids = []

                for (i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                    hitids.push('#n' + hits[i].id)
                }
                let idstoget = hitids.toString()

                let forceids = d3.selectAll(idstoget)

                simulation.force('x', d3.forceX().strength(10).x(radiusPoint[0]))
                simulation.force('y', d3.forceY().strength(10).y(radiusPoint[1]))

                // simulation.force('center', d3.forceCenter(radiusPoint[0], radiusPoint[1]))

                simulation.alpha(1).restart()

                simulation.nodes(forceids)
                    .on('tick', ticked)

                function ticked() {
                    update(forceids)
                }

                function update(forceids) {

                    forceids
                        .attr('cx', function (d) { return d.x })
                        .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y })
                }
            }
        }

        function nearest(node, radius, hits) {
            if (!hits) hits = [];
            var r = radius,
                nx1 = node.longitude - r,
                nx2 = node.longitude + r,
                ny1 = node.latitude - r,
                ny2 = node.latitude + r;

            return function (quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                if (quad.data && (quad.data !== node)) {
                    var x = node.longitude - quad.data.longitude,
                        y = node.latitude - quad.data.latitude,
                        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                        r = radius;
                    if (l < r) {
                        hits.push(quad.data)
                    } else {
                    }
                }
                return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
            }
        }
```

```css
        .tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 15px;
            font: 12px sans-serif;
            background: #fff;
            color: #000;
            border: 0px;
            pointer-events: none;
            opacity: 0.8;
            visibility: hidden;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #aaa;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #aaa;
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px #aaa;
        }

        .close {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 1 px;
        }

        .multiple-choice {
            padding: 3px 0;
        }

        .radius {
            fill-opacity: 0.15;
            stroke: #333;
            stroke-dasharray: 4 2;
            z-index: 1000;
            fill: #bff4ff;
            display: none;
        }

        #panel {
            position: absolute;
            left: 1030px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 300px;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }

        .list-item {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        label {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        #hitnumber {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-quadtree@3"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/geo-albers-usa-territories@0.1.0/dist/geo-albers-usa-territories.js"></script>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <div id="list">
            <div id="hitnumber"></div>
            <pre><div id="hits"></div></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="chart-title"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*While I'd be tempted to not use a force layout for this, I'll work with the code you have here (though the question of the lines connecting the circles to their original location is not addressed here) and quickly address why the circles do not behave as you expect.*

A force layout will create the appropriate properties on a node if they don't exist. For position of a node, these properties are d.x and d.y. Your data does not have x or y properties, so when you create the force, the nodes are initialized with values around the origin, [0,0], which is why they migrate to the top left corner. This problem can be solved by creating x and y properties:

```
.each(d=>[d.x,d.y] = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]))
```

In the snippet below I use this right after positioning the circles on enter.

Secondly, you want to pass the bound datums to the force layout not the nodes (otherwise, as the nodes themselves don't have x,y properties, we'll initialize them in the top left again). We also don't want to pass the selection as the nodes, instead, let's access the selection's data:

```
simulation.nodes(forceids.data())
```

Which, with a quick and dirty few lines to reset the moved nodes (using the lat/long, and resetting x,y to the lat/long), gives us:

```js
let margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10, left: 0 },
            width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        let projection = geoAlbersUsaTerritories.geoAlbersUsaTerritories()
            .scale(width)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2.2]);

        const path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
            .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-160))
            .stop()

        let eventX,
            eventY

        const formatDate2 = d3.timeFormat("%m-%Y")

        const svg = d3.select("#content")
            .append("svg")
            .attr('id', 'map')
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

        const map = svg.append('g')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
            .attr('class', 'map')

        const landmass = map.append('g').attr('class', 'land')

        const places = map.append('g').attr('id', 'places')

        svg.append('ellipse').classed("radius", true).attr('id', 'locate')

        d3.json("https://unpkg.com/us-atlas@3.0.0/states-10m.json").then(function (usa) {

            landmass.selectAll('path')
                .data(topojson.feature(usa, usa.objects.nation).features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("class", "outline")
                .attr('fill', '#ccc')
                .attr("stroke", "#999")

            landmass.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(usa, usa.objects.states, function (a, b) { return a !== b; }))
                .attr("class", "mesh")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr('fill', 'none')
                .attr('stroke', 'white')
        });

        const data = [
            {
                "id": 3448,
                "name": "General Edward Lawrence Logan Intl",
                "city": "Boston",
                "faa": "BOS",
                "latitude": 42.364347,
                "longitude": -71.005181
            },
            {
                "id": 3453,
                "name": "Metropolitan Oakland Intl",
                "city": "Oakland",
                "faa": "OAK",
                "latitude": 37.721278,
                "longitude": -122.220722
            },
            {
                "id": 3454,
                "name": "Eppley Afld",
                "city": "Omaha",
                "faa": "OMA",
                "latitude": 41.303167,
                "longitude": -95.894069
            },
            {
                "id": 3457,
                "name": "Wichita Mid Continent",
                "city": "Wichita",
                "faa": "ICT",
                "latitude": 37.649944,
                "longitude": -97.433056
            },
            {
                "id": 3458,
                "name": "Kansas City Intl",
                "city": "Kansas City",
                "faa": "MCI",
                "latitude": 39.297606,
                "longitude": -94.713905
            },
            {
                "id": 3459,
                "name": "Dane Co Rgnl Truax Fld",
                "city": "Madison",
                "faa": "MSN",
                "latitude": 43.139858,
                "longitude": -89.337514
            },
            {
                "id": 3462,
                "name": "Phoenix Sky Harbor Intl",
                "city": "Phoenix",
                "faa": "PHX",
                "latitude": 33.434278,
                "longitude": -112.011583
            },
            {
                "id": 3467,
                "name": "Spokane Intl",
                "city": "Spokane",
                "faa": "GEG",
                "latitude": 47.619861,
                "longitude": -117.533833
            },
            {
                "id": 3469,
                "name": "San Francisco Intl",
                "city": "San Francisco",
                "faa": "SFO",
                "latitude": 37.618972,
                "longitude": -122.374889
            },
            {
                "id": 3472,
                "name": "Gainesville Rgnl",
                "city": "Gainesville",
                "faa": "GNV",
                "latitude": 29.690056,
                "longitude": -82.271778
            },
            {
                "id": 3473,
                "name": "Memphis Intl",
                "city": "Memphis",
                "faa": "MEM",
                "latitude": 35.042417,
                "longitude": -89.976667
            },
            {
                "id": 3484,
                "name": "Los Angeles Intl",
                "city": "Los Angeles",
                "faa": "LAX",
                "latitude": 33.942536,
                "longitude": -118.408075
            },
            {
                "id": 3486,
                "name": "Cleveland Hopkins Intl",
                "city": "Cleveland",
                "faa": "CLE",
                "latitude": 41.411689,
                "longitude": -81.849794
            },            
            {
                "id": 3494,
                "name": "Newark Liberty Intl",
                "city": "Newark",
                "faa": "EWR",
                "latitude": 40.6925,
                "longitude": -74.168667
            },
            {
                "id": 3502,
                "name": "Dallas Love Fld",
                "city": "Dallas",
                "faa": "DAL",
                "latitude": 32.847111,
                "longitude": -96.851778
            },
            {
                "id": 3550,
                "name": "George Bush Intercontinental",
                "city": "Houston",
                "faa": "IAH",
                "latitude": 29.984433,
                "longitude": -95.341442
            },
            {
                "id": 3559,
                "name": "El Paso Intl",
                "city": "El Paso",
                "faa": "ELP",
                "latitude": 31.80725,
                "longitude": -106.377583
            },
            {
                "id": 3566,
                "name": "William P Hobby",
                "city": "Houston",
                "faa": "HOU",
                "latitude": 29.645419,
                "longitude": -95.278889
            },
            {
                "id": 3570,
                "name": "Pittsburgh Intl",
                "city": "Pittsburgh",
                "faa": "PIT",
                "latitude": 40.491467,
                "longitude": -80.232872
            },
            {
                "id": 3576,
                "name": "Miami Intl",
                "city": "Miami",
                "faa": "MIA",
                "latitude": 25.79325,
                "longitude": -80.290556
            },
            {
                "id": 3582,
                "name": "Long Beach",
                "city": "Long Beach",
                "faa": "LGB",
                "latitude": 33.817722,
                "longitude": -118.151611
            },
            {
                "id": 3585,
                "name": "Indianapolis Intl",
                "city": "Indianapolis",
                "faa": "IND",
                "latitude": 39.717331,
                "longitude": -86.294383
            },
            {
                "id": 3589,
                "name": "Westchester Co",
                "city": "White Plains",
                "faa": "HPN",
                "latitude": 41.066959,
                "longitude": -73.707575
            },
            {
                "id": 3697,
                "name": "La Guardia",
                "city": "New York",
                "faa": "LGA",
                "latitude": 40.777245,
                "longitude": -73.872608
            },
            {
                "id": 3747,
                "name": "Chicago Midway Intl",
                "city": "Chicago",
                "faa": "MDW",
                "latitude": 41.785972,
                "longitude": -87.752417
            },
            {
                "id": 3797,
                "name": "John F Kennedy Intl",
                "city": "New York",
                "faa": "JFK",
                "latitude": 40.639751,
                "longitude": -73.778925
            },
            {
                "id": 3830,
                "name": "Chicago Ohare Intl",
                "city": "Chicago",
                "faa": "ORD",
                "latitude": 41.978603,
                "longitude": -87.904842
            }
        ]

        d3.selectAll('.close').on('click', function () {
            d3.selectAll('.popup').remove()
        })
        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.latitude = +d.latitude;
            d.longitude = +d.longitude;
        })
        d3.selectAll('.location').remove()

        let locations = places.selectAll(".location")
            .data(data);

        locations.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr('id', d => 'n' + d.id)
            .attr("class", 'location')
            .attr('cx', d => projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0])
            .attr('cy', d => projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1])
            .each(d=>[d.x,d.y] = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]))
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr('fill', 'green')
            .style('stroke', '#fff')
            .style('stroke-width', .5)
            .style("opacity", .75)
            .on('click', function (event, d) {
                simulation.stop()

                var isSelectedCode = d.detention_facility_code
                var isSelectedName = d.name
                var whichclass = d3.select(this).attr("class").split(' ');
                let activeIndex = whichclass.indexOf('active')

                var sel = d3.select(this);
                sel.raise();

                let latlng = [d.longitude, d.latitude]
                $('#clickedFacility').text(d.name)
                $('#slider').removeClass('hide')
                showRadius(latlng, far)

            })
            .on("mouseover", function (event, d) {
                var sel = d3.select(this);
                sel.raise();

                let tooltip_str = d.name
                tooltip.html(tooltip_str)
                    .style("visibility", "visible");
            })
            .on("mousemove", function (event, d) {
                tooltip.style("top", event.pageY - (tooltip.node().clientHeight + 5) + "px")
                    .style("left", event.pageX - (tooltip.node().clientWidth / 2.0) + "px");
            })
            .on("mouseout", function (event, d) {
                var sel = d3.select(this);
                sel.lower();
                tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
            })

        locations
            .transition()
            .duration(100)
            .attr("class", d => "location " + d.name.replace(/[\s]/g, '') + ' ' + d.type_detailed.replace(/\s+|[,\/]/g, "") + ' closed' + d.is_closed)
            .attr("r", 5)
            .attr('fill', 'green')

        locations.exit()
            .remove();

        const tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip");

        var info = svg.append("div")
            .attr("class", "info");

        const quadtree = d3.quadtree()
            .x(d => +d.longitude)
            .y(d => +d.latitude)
            .addAll(data);

        let miles = 30

        let far = (1 / 60) * miles; // in degrees

        function showRadius(evt, far) {
        
            // Reset //
             svg.selectAll('circle')
                 .attr('cx', d => d.x = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0])
                 .attr('cy', d => d.y = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1])       
                 .attr('fill', 'green')
            /////
        

            d3.select('ellipse.radius').remove();

            let radiusCircle = map.append("ellipse").classed("radius", true).attr('id', 'locate')

            let xy = projection.invert(evt)
            console.log('xy', xy)

            let xyObject = { "longitude": evt[0], "latitude": evt[1] }
            radiusLng = evt[0] + far
            radiusLat = evt[1] + far
            radiusLngLat = [+radiusLng, +radiusLat]
            radiusPoint = projection(radiusLngLat)
            console.log('radiusPoint', radiusPoint)

            radiusX = Math.abs(evt[1] + far)
            radiusY = Math.abs(evt[0] + far)

            radiusToPoint = projection([radiusY, radiusX][0])

            d3.select('ellipse.radius').classed('hide', false)
            d3.select('ellipse.radius').classed('show', true)

            let radiusprojx = projection(evt)[0]
            let radiusprojxN = projection(evt)[0] - eventX
            let radiusprojy = projection(evt)[1]
            let radiusprojyN = projection(evt)[1] - eventY

            radiusCircle
                .attr('cx', d => (projection(evt)[0]))
                .attr('cy', d => (projection(evt)[1]))
                .attr('rx', 20)
                .attr('ry', 20)

            let hits = [];
            quadtree.visit(nearest(xyObject, far, hits))

            for (i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                let line = turf.lineString([[evt[1], evt[0]], [hits[i].latitude, hits[i].longitude]]);
                let length = turf.length(line, { units: 'miles' });
                hits[i].distance = +length.toFixed(2) + ' miles';
            }
            hits.sort(function (a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.distance, b.distance) })

            let locationsInRadius = hits.map(a => a.id);
            //console.log('locationsInRadius', locationsInRadius)

            d3.selectAll('.location').attr('fill', 'green')
            locationsInRadius.forEach(function (d, i) {
                d3.select('#n' + d).attr('fill', 'blue')
            })

            let total_count = hits.length

            $("#hitnumber").text(total_count + " airports within 30 miles")

            d3.selectAll('.list-item').remove()

            let listItem = d3.selectAll('#hits').selectAll('text')
                .data(hits)
                .attr('padding-left', '20px')
                .enter().append('div').attr('class', 'list-item')
                .html(d => d.name + "<br/>Lat: " + d.latitude + "<br/>Lng: " + d.longitude + "<br/>Distance: " + d.distance)

            if (hits.length == 1) {
            } else {
                const hitids = []

                for (i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                    hitids.push('#n' + hits[i].id)
                }
                let idstoget = hitids.toString()

                let forceids = d3.selectAll(idstoget)

                simulation.force('x', d3.forceX().strength(0.1).x(radiusPoint[0]))
                simulation.force('y', d3.forceY().strength(0.1).y(radiusPoint[1]))

                // simulation.force('center', d3.forceCenter(radiusPoint[0], radiusPoint[1]))

                simulation.alpha(1).restart()

                simulation.nodes(forceids.data())
                    .on('tick', ticked)

                function ticked() {
                    update(forceids)
                }

                function update(forceids) {

                    forceids
                        .attr('cx', function (d) { return d.x })
                        .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y })
                }
            }
        }

        function nearest(node, radius, hits) {
            if (!hits) hits = [];
            var r = radius,
                nx1 = node.longitude - r,
                nx2 = node.longitude + r,
                ny1 = node.latitude - r,
                ny2 = node.latitude + r;

            return function (quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
                if (quad.data && (quad.data !== node)) {
                    var x = node.longitude - quad.data.longitude,
                        y = node.latitude - quad.data.latitude,
                        l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                        r = radius;
                    if (l < r) {
                        hits.push(quad.data)
                    } else {
                    }
                }
                return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
            }
        }
```

```css
.tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            padding: 15px;
            font: 12px sans-serif;
            background: #fff;
            color: #000;
            border: 0px;
            pointer-events: none;
            opacity: 0.8;
            visibility: hidden;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #aaa;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #aaa;
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px #aaa;
        }

        .close {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 1 px;
        }

        .multiple-choice {
            padding: 3px 0;
        }

        .radius {
            fill-opacity: 0.15;
            stroke: #333;
            stroke-dasharray: 4 2;
            z-index: 1000;
            fill: #bff4ff;
            display: none;
        }

        #panel {
            position: absolute;
            left: 1030px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 300px;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }

        .list-item {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        label {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        #hitnumber {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-quadtree@3"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/geo-albers-usa-territories@0.1.0/dist/geo-albers-usa-territories.js"></script>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <div id="list">
            <div id="hitnumber"></div>
            <pre><div id="hits"></div></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="chart-title"></div>
```